# Frequency count in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to classify this data into two csv files. If the file name has `1` frequency it'll save to `single_face.csv` and the others will be saved to `multi_faces.csv`

What I've done is to get the frequencies of my data, this is what it looks like:

```
21_Festival_Festival_21_68.jpg                                                     346
8_Election_Campain_Election_Campaign_8_531.jpg                                     278
2_Demonstration_Demonstration_Or_Protest_2_17.jpg                                  266
18_Concerts_Concerts_18_542.jpg                                                    218
10_People_Marching_People_Marching_10_People_Marching_People_Marching_10_88.jpg    209
                                                                                  ... 
36_Football_americanfootball_ball_36_53.jpg                                          1
48_Parachutist_Paratrooper_Parachutist_Paratrooper_48_48.jpg                         1
55_Sports_Coach_Trainer_sportcoaching_55_837.jpg                                     1
22_Picnic_Picnic_22_586.jpg                                                          1
9_Press_Conference_Press_Conference_9_873.jpg                                        1
```

and this is my code:

```py
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd

def classification(file):

    df= pd.read_csv(file)

    frequency = df['file_name'].value_counts('1')
    print (frequency)

def main():

    classification('ground_truth.csv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How can I separate this data into two csv files? I tried to use `if frequency == 1:` but this results in an error.

Comment: Could you share the data in a format that is easier for people to use? See: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the conditions as an index into your `Series` and use `.to_csv()` for each of those:

```
In [4]: s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1, 4, 20), index=list("abcdefghijkilmnopqrs"))

In [5]: s[s == 1]
Out[5]:
a    1
g    1
k    1
s    1
dtype: int32

In [6]: s[s > 1]
Out[6]:
b    2
c    3
d    3
e    2
f    2
h    2
i    2
j    2
i    2
l    3
m    3
n    2
o    3
p    2
q    2
r    3
dtype: int32

In [7]: s[s > 1].to_csv("multi.csv")
```